# Should I use random fixed mutation or random percentual mutation?

Tags: neural-networks, genetic-algorithms

I'm evolving neural networks, partly by mutating connection weights and neuron biases. Right now i'm mutating weights as follows:

```
modification = random() * 2 - 1; // number between -1 and 1
weight += modification
```

But I realised that for smaller weights (e.g. `0.03`) this modification might be too big. Should I change this code to percentual mutation, like this:

```
// Mutate the weight between -10% and 10%
weight = weight * (1 + (random() * 0.2 - 0.1));
```

Which technique is better? Are there any papers on percentual mutation?

Edit: i'm noticing much better performance with the fixed mutation

Comment: I'm not aware of a direct comparison of this sort, but don't take that as much evidence that none exist. One thing I'd add though is that the idea of a Gaussian mutation is pretty well established in the literature. That is, you mutate by sampling a normal distribution with zero mean and some parameterized standard deviation $\sigma$. That gives you generally small mutations with some probability of larger ones as well.

The evolution strategies approach treats the $\sigma$ parameter as part of each individual, so it would evolve alongside each weight independently.

Comment: It depends on how large the network is. If it is small, even small change in weights can ruin it. If it is larger than you don't need to worry as much because rest of the network remains stable and population is unlikely to suffer larger setbacks because of few unlucky rolls.